# Play audio file when object detected in OpenCV - python3

Tags: python, opencv, pygame, raspberry-pi

First time poster so forgive if I miss anything important.

I am currently working on an object / facial recognition camera that detects birds on the RaspberryPi 4B. When a bird is detected, an mp3 file should play through a connected Bluetooth speaker.

I currently have a python script that works for bird detection using the OpenCV Library and a python script that works to play the mp3 using pygame. But what I am struggling to do is combine to two together so that when a bird a detected, the pygame mp3 plays through bluetooth.

1. Is this possible to do?
2. If so, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried initialising + loading the pygame script at the beginning of the facial recognition script and then adding the sound playback within the while true loop at the end but it didn't work out.

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame import mixer

#initilise / start mixer
mixer.init()

#load the file
mixer.music.load("Duck-quack.mp3")

#set volume
mixer.music.set_volume(1.0)

#Start playing song
mixer.music.play()
```

```
import cv2
import pygame as pg

classNames = []
classFile = "/home/pi/Desktop/Object_Detection_Files/coco.names"
with open(classFile,"rt") as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip("\n").split("\n")

configPath = "/home/pi/Desktop/Object_Detection_Files/ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt"
weightsPath = "/home/pi/Desktop/Object_Detection_Files/frozen_inference_graph.pb"

net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath,configPath)
net.setInputSize(320,320)
net.setInputScale(1.0/ 127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)


def getObjects(img, thres, nms, draw=True, objects=[]):
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img,confThreshold=thres,nmsThreshold=nms)
    #print(classIds,bbox)
    if len(objects) == 0: objects = classNames
    objectInfo =[]
    if len(classIds) != 0:
        for classId, confidence,box in zip(classIds.flatten(),confs.flatten(),bbox):
            className = classNames[classId - 1]
            if className in objects:
                objectInfo.append([box,className])
                if (draw):
                    cv2.rectangle(img,box,color=(0,255,0),thickness=2)
                    cv2.putText(img,classNames[classId-1].upper(),(box[0]+10,box[1]+30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)
                    cv2.putText(img,str(round(confidence*100,2)),(box[0]+200,box[1]+30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)

    return img,objectInfo


if __name__ == "__main__":

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(3,640)
    cap.set(4,480)
    #cap.set(10,70)


    while True:
        #threshold of object accuracy = 0.60
        success, img = cap.read()
        result, objectInfo = getObjects(img,0.50,0.2, objects=['bird'])
        
        #print(objectInfo)
        cv2.imshow("Output",img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: where do you attempt to play the audio file? I don't see an attempt to implement that. you only showed two unrelated pieces of code.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to play the music once when an object is detected. Call [`mixer.music.play()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play) (with no argument or default argument 0) when there is an object in `objectInfo` is located. Avoid restarting the music before it's done. Test whether the mixer is busy with [`pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.get_busy):

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":

    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load("Duck-quack.mp3")

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(3,640)
    cap.set(4,480)
    #cap.set(10,70)


    while True:
        #threshold of object accuracy = 0.60
        success, img = cap.read()
        
        result, objectInfo = getObjects(img,0.50,0.2, objects=['bird'])
        if objectInfo and not mixer.music.get_busy():
            mixer.music.play()
        
        #print(objectInfo)
        cv2.imshow("Output",img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```